# Composer Package Error

Tags: github, package, composer-php, versioning, gravatar

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.

I've created a package and I'm trying to require it by using this:

`composer require "karl-ballard/gravatar" : "1.0.*"`

However, I keep getting this as an output:

```
InvalidArgumentException

Could not find package 1.0.* at any version for your minimum-stability
(stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
https://github.com/krballard/gravatar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong, see [Docs for Composer `require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require).

You copied the line for `composer.json` directly to the command line.

It's `composer require "karl-ballard/gravatar:^1.0"`

Comment: Easiest way to install and avoid these conflicts is without any version: `composer require karl-ballard/gravatar`. Composer picks last stable by default.